# VBA Word - Cells do not insert properly

Tags: vba, ms-word

In a previous post I discussed trying to add a column to the end of a table with merged cells. Some of the suggestions pointed me in a better direction but I have not fully fixed the issue. ([Word VBA - Add column to the right end of a table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76584030/word-vba-add-column-to-the-right-end-of-a-table))

I can find and select the last cell in each row of the table, but adding cells does not put them on the right side.

This is one of the tables I'm working with. [Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zVMBo.png)

Using the code below results in cells being added to the left of some cells, but not all of them. [Table after execution of `test()`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gr6La.png)
I changed the view to Draft to fit the full table size.

```
Sub test()

    Dim t As Table, cel As Cell, colMax As Long
    Set t = ActiveDocument.Tables(1)

    For Each cel In t.Range.Cells

        cel.Select
        colMax = Selection.Information(wdMaximumNumberOfColumns)
    
        If cel.ColumnIndex = colMax Then
            
            Debug.Print "Cell ("; cel.RowIndex; ", "; cel.ColumnIndex; ") is the last cell in its row."
            
            cel.Select
            Selection.Cells.Add
            
        End If
        
    Next cel

End Sub
```

Using the code below, as a previous user suggested, results in a similar situation where a new column is added to the right of the first column, but not the last. [Table after execution of `example()`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X2w7c.png)

```
Sub example()

    Dim t As Table
    Set t = ActiveDocument.Tables(1)

    t.Columns.Add

End Sub
```

Using `Columns.Last` throws the following error.

Run-time error '5992':
Cannot access individual columns in this selection because the table has mixed cell widths.

Comment: *Tim Williams* has provided a good answer, and this post is similar to or a duplicate of the one [you ask before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76584030/word-vba-add-column-to-the-right-end-of-a-table) and I've answered at the same time too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Performing the insert by triggering the ribbon menu control seems to work more reliably:

```vb
Sub Tester()
    
    Dim tbl As Table, c As Cell, rw As Row, i As Long, cLast As Cell
   
    Set tbl = ThisDocument.Tables(1) 'for example

    For Each c In tbl.Range.Cells
        If cLast Is Nothing Then Set cLast = c
        If c.ColumnIndex > cLast.ColumnIndex Then Set cLast = c
        'c.Range.Text = "R" & c.RowIndex & ":C" & c.ColumnIndex
    Next c

    cLast.Select 'select any of the cells which share max. columnIndex
    DoEvents 'just in case
    
    Application.CommandBars.ExecuteMso "TableColumnsInsertRight"
   
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Just like [my logic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76592525/8249058), and thank you for `Application.CommandBars.ExecuteMso "TableColumnsInsertRight"` promoting me.

Comment: @OscarSun - sorry I did see the previous post but had not seen your answer there...

Comment: Sure, cause we were answering these two questions at the same time almost. :) Thank you again for your implementation to enlighten me indeed. I'll remember this method *ExecuteMso*, because whilst I tested the code, it was indeed *"Performing the insert by triggering the ribbon menu control seems to work more reliably"* rather than the method **InsertColumnsRight** which macro command recorded.

Comment: So far, your solution seems to be the best and most stable, and fast. [see why](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76592525/8249058).

Comment: @TimWilliams thank you for contributing and finding a solution! This will save me a ton of time and I appreciate your work!

Comment: @OscarSun thank you for contributing and finding a solution! This will save me a ton of time and I appreciate your work!

Comment: @Nate Then would you mind accepting these two answers to close your questions?