# Paragraph style copy/renaming

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a bunch of document that has X Heading Y (BT Heading 1, BT Heading 2, BT Heading 3) format instead of Heading 1, Heading 2, Heading 3)... so they won't show up in cross reference / heading.

Is there a way to write a VBA to rename these, or to copy the format from X Heading Y to Heading Y ?

Thanks so much in advance!

Searched online but couldn't find any related articles.

[image]

Comment: You can’t rename those styles as Heading 1 to Heading 9 are built-in styles, so have reserved names. If the documents are all based on a common template you can modify the built-in heading styles to match the custom ones. Then you can update the styles in the document from the template. Finally, you can use Find and Replace to apply the correct styles.

Comment: Can you give us a sample and screenshot to understand exactly what situation you met?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Timothy Rylatt* is right, you can refer to his point and implement it, the following code I implemented is a similar one, you can try first:

```vb
Sub Paragraph_style_copy_renaming()
    Dim destStyleName, sourceStyleName, d As Word.Document, e, i
    destStyleName = Array("BT Heading 1", "BT Heading 2", "BT Heading 3")
    sourceStyleName = Array(WdBuiltinStyle.wdStyleHeading1, WdBuiltinStyle.wdStyleHeading2, WdBuiltinStyle.wdStyleHeading3)
    Set d = ActiveDocument
    For Each e In sourceStyleName
        UpdateStyle2RangeStyle d.Styles(e), d.Styles(destStyleName(i))
        i = i + 1
    Next e
    i = 0
    With d.Range.Find
        .ClearAllFuzzyOptions
        .ClearFormatting
        For Each e In destStyleName
            .Style = d.Styles(e)
            .Wrap = wdFindContinue
            .Replacement.Style = sourceStyleName(i)
            .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
            i = i + 1
        Next e
    End With
End Sub


Sub UpdateStyle2RangeStyle(sourceStyle As Style, destStyle As Style)
    sourceStyle.AutomaticallyUpdate = destStyle.AutomaticallyUpdate
    With sourceStyle.Font
        .NameFarEast = destStyle.Font.NameFarEast
        .NameAscii = destStyle.Font.NameAscii
        .NameOther = destStyle.Font.NameOther
        .Name = destStyle.Font.Name
        .Size = destStyle.Font.Size
        .Bold = destStyle.Font.Bold
        .Italic = destStyle.Font.Italic
        .Underline = destStyle.Font.Underline
        .UnderlineColor = destStyle.Font.UnderlineColor
        .StrikeThrough = destStyle.Font.StrikeThrough
        .DoubleStrikeThrough = destStyle.Font.DoubleStrikeThrough
        .Outline = destStyle.Font.Outline
        .Emboss = destStyle.Font.Emboss
        .Shadow = destStyle.Font.Shadow
        .Hidden = destStyle.Font.Hidden
        .SmallCaps = destStyle.Font.SmallCaps
        .AllCaps = destStyle.Font.AllCaps
        .Color = destStyle.Font.Color
        .Engrave = destStyle.Font.Engrave
        .Superscript = destStyle.Font.Superscript
        .Subscript = destStyle.Font.Subscript
        .Scaling = destStyle.Font.Scaling
        .Kerning = destStyle.Font.Kerning
        .Animation = destStyle.Font.Animation
        .DisableCharacterSpaceGrid = destStyle.Font.DisableCharacterSpaceGrid
        .EmphasisMark = destStyle.Font.EmphasisMark
        .Ligatures = destStyle.Font.Ligatures
        .NumberSpacing = destStyle.Font.NumberSpacing
        .NumberForm = destStyle.Font.NumberForm
        .StylisticSet = destStyle.Font.StylisticSet
        .ContextualAlternates = destStyle.Font.ContextualAlternates
    End With
    With sourceStyle.ParagraphFormat
        .LeftIndent = destStyle.ParagraphFormat.LeftIndent
        .RightIndent = destStyle.ParagraphFormat.RightIndent
        .SpaceBefore = destStyle.ParagraphFormat.SpaceBefore
        .SpaceBeforeAuto = destStyle.ParagraphFormat.SpaceBeforeAuto
        .SpaceAfter = destStyle.ParagraphFormat.SpaceAfter
        .SpaceAfterAuto = destStyle.ParagraphFormat.SpaceAfterAuto
        .LineSpacingRule = destStyle.ParagraphFormat.LineSpacingRule
        .LineSpacing = destStyle.ParagraphFormat.LineSpacing
        .Alignment = destStyle.ParagraphFormat.Alignment
        .WidowControl = destStyle.ParagraphFormat.WidowControl
        .KeepWithNext = destStyle.ParagraphFormat.KeepWithNext
        .KeepTogether = destStyle.ParagraphFormat.KeepTogether
        .PageBreakBefore = destStyle.ParagraphFormat.PageBreakBefore
        .NoLineNumber = destStyle.ParagraphFormat.NoLineNumber
        .Hyphenation = destStyle.ParagraphFormat.Hyphenation
        .FirstLineIndent = destStyle.ParagraphFormat.FirstLineIndent
        .OutlineLevel = destStyle.ParagraphFormat.OutlineLevel
        .CharacterUnitLeftIndent = destStyle.ParagraphFormat.CharacterUnitLeftIndent
        .CharacterUnitRightIndent = destStyle.ParagraphFormat.CharacterUnitRightIndent
        .CharacterUnitFirstLineIndent = destStyle.ParagraphFormat.CharacterUnitFirstLineIndent
        .LineUnitBefore = destStyle.ParagraphFormat.LineUnitBefore
        .LineUnitAfter = destStyle.ParagraphFormat.LineUnitAfter
        .MirrorIndents = destStyle.ParagraphFormat.MirrorIndents
        .TextboxTightWrap = destStyle.ParagraphFormat.TextboxTightWrap
        .CollapsedByDefault = destStyle.ParagraphFormat.CollapsedByDefault
        .AutoAdjustRightIndent = destStyle.ParagraphFormat.AutoAdjustRightIndent
        .DisableLineHeightGrid = destStyle.ParagraphFormat.DisableLineHeightGrid
        .FarEastLineBreakControl = destStyle.ParagraphFormat.FarEastLineBreakControl
        .WordWrap = destStyle.ParagraphFormat.WordWrap
        .HangingPunctuation = destStyle.ParagraphFormat.HangingPunctuation
        .HalfWidthPunctuationOnTopOfLine = destStyle.ParagraphFormat.HalfWidthPunctuationOnTopOfLine
        .AddSpaceBetweenFarEastAndAlpha = destStyle.ParagraphFormat.AddSpaceBetweenFarEastAndAlpha
        .AddSpaceBetweenFarEastAndDigit = destStyle.ParagraphFormat.AddSpaceBetweenFarEastAndDigit
        .BaseLineAlignment = destStyle.ParagraphFormat.BaseLineAlignment
    End With
    sourceStyle.NoSpaceBetweenParagraphsOfSameStyle = destStyle.NoSpaceBetweenParagraphsOfSameStyle
    sourceStyle.ParagraphFormat.TabStops.ClearAll
    With sourceStyle.ParagraphFormat
        With .Shading
            .Texture = destStyle.ParagraphFormat.Shading.Texture
            .ForegroundPatternColor = destStyle.ParagraphFormat.Shading.ForegroundPatternColor
            .BackgroundPatternColor = destStyle.ParagraphFormat.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor
        End With
        .Borders(wdBorderLeft).LineStyle = destStyle.ParagraphFormat.Borders(wdBorderLeft).LineStyle
        .Borders(wdBorderRight).LineStyle = destStyle.ParagraphFormat.Borders(wdBorderRight).LineStyle
        .Borders(wdBorderTop).LineStyle = destStyle.ParagraphFormat.Borders(wdBorderTop).LineStyle
        .Borders(wdBorderBottom).LineStyle = destStyle.ParagraphFormat.Borders(wdBorderBottom).LineStyle
        With .Borders
            .DistanceFromTop = destStyle.ParagraphFormat.Borders.DistanceFromTop
            .DistanceFromLeft = destStyle.ParagraphFormat.Borders.DistanceFromLeft
            .DistanceFromBottom = destStyle.ParagraphFormat.Borders.DistanceFromBottom
            .DistanceFromRight = destStyle.ParagraphFormat.Borders.DistanceFromRight
            .Shadow = destStyle.ParagraphFormat.Borders.Shadow
        End With
    End With
    sourceStyle.LanguageID = destStyle.LanguageID
    sourceStyle.NoProofing = destStyle.NoProofing
    sourceStyle.LanguageID = destStyle.LanguageID
    sourceStyle.NoProofing = destStyle.NoProofing
    sourceStyle.Frame.Delete
End Sub
```

I'd like to find out the argument of the **Application.CommandBars.[ExecuteMso](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/office.commandbars.executemso)** to do this update style mission just like following [Tim's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76592306/8249058) to easily and accurately accomplish with agility, however, I couldn't find it. Just found something like it([Options.UpdateStyleListBehavior property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.options.updatestylelistbehavior)), but should be not this. Thus the only way to achieve it was to record a macro to simulate and reproduce all the relevant properties and methods. So if there are any omissions, please take note of them.

- Before
  [image]
- After
  [image]

Comment: Thanks Oscar. I created a graphics to illustrate this, but will definitely try your code on Monday...  how do I post an image?

Comment: @user22139624 You should already have the privilege to post pictures. Just edit it directly in your post. If you copy the screenshot you want to paste (which I always do) into your clipboard and press paste (Ctrl + v or Shift + Insert), it will automatically generate the source code for the image in the post. Then you can just update your post and you're done.

Comment: Oscar, this worked well. Had to remove some font packages that I don't have ;-) Thanks again !  Also I had to add a loop to remove numbering on all my Headings... 
 oPara.range.ListFormat.RemoveNumbers NumberType:=wdNumberParagraph
       End If

Comment: @user22139624 Ok, you'll get thru it. Good luck.